# s3cmd put only files that do not exist in destination bucket

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I've been using [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org) to sync local files on our server with the S3 bucket. There are over 200,000 files on the local server. Can't seem to find any documentation on the site that explains how to upload ONLY files that do not exist in the destination bucket? It appears to be uploading all files every time.

What is the command to sync ONLY files that:

- Do not exist in the destination bucket
- Do exist in the destination bucket, but have different last-modified date, or different filesize

Here is the command I've been using:

```
> s3cmd put [DIRECTORY] --recursive s3://[BUCKET]/[PATH]/
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ s3cmd sync <source> <dest>
```